# Loosing the value of global variable while using it with two functions one of which is recursive

Tags: c

I do not understand what is going on in my code... I declared global variable that I could use between two functions, one of which is recursive. But I face with problem that each time my code is going out of recursive function my value in the global variable is set again to zero value. Though it must contain EOF value to terminate while loop.

The global variable:
int currChar;

Used here:

```
int currChar; // <-- GLOBAL VAR

int createStructureRec(FILE *fp, Node *temp){
    int currChar = getc(fp); //<-- I WAS STUPID HERE!!!!
    if (currChar != EOF ) currChar = charToIndex(currChar);
    if(currChar == EOF || currChar == -1){
        temp -> numOfOccur++;
        if(temp -> numOfOccur == 1){
            temp -> numOfSuperWords--;
            return 1;
        }
        else return 0;
    }

    int returnValue = 0;
    if (temp -> children[currChar].children == NULL){
        temp -> children[currChar].children = (Node *)calloc(27, sizeof(struct node));
        temp -> children[currChar].numOfOccur = 0;
        temp -> children[currChar].numOfSuperWords = 0;
        temp = &temp -> children[currChar];
        returnValue = createStructureRec(fp, temp);
    }else{
        temp = &temp -> children[currChar];
        returnValue = createStructureRec(fp, temp);
    }
    temp -> numOfSuperWords += returnValue;
    return returnValue;
}
```

So inside this function I am getting zero value for my global var each time, thus loop never terminates.

```
void createStructure(FILE *fp){

    root.numOfOccur = 0;
    root.children = (Node *)calloc(27, sizeof(struct node));
    currChar = 0;
    Node* temp = &root;

    while (currChar != EOF) 
        createStructureRec(fp, temp);
}
```

Please, help!

Comment: Your global variable is never written when you have a local one with the same name.

Comment: @mfro Oh JEEZ... I am total idiot. You can minus me.. ((( I was debugging for hours..but.. this..so stupid ((( Thanks. You can answer the question so I will select it. Sorry and thanks

Comment: +1 for `int currChar = getc(fp); //<-- I WAS STUPID HERE!!!!`

Answer (score 4):

Change:

```
int createStructureRec(FILE *fp, Node *temp){
    int currChar = getc(fp);
```

to:

```
int createStructureRec(FILE *fp, Node *temp){
    currChar = getc(fp);
```

You have declared a local variable `currChar` with the same name and this local variable is used instead the global one.

Comment: Yes, I am stupid.. I understood it already...  :((( Thanks
Stupid mistake that I did not notice took me hours of debugging.. (((

Comment: Good, you can go further now :) (and check the answer :p)